# Some keyboard keys not working since upgrade to 11.10

Tags: installation, upgrade, keyboard, laptop, bios

II.04 was working perfectly on my Acer Aspire 3050 laptop, until I upgraded a couple of days ago.  Yesterday, I was unable to type in my password as only about half the keys on kb are working.  I logged in on a guest account, but couldn't do anything or access Internet because I needed to type in my pw to do so.

Decided to do a fresh install of 11.04. however I can't enter BIOS using the designated key (F2) to make it boot from CD.  Guessing that it's one of the non-functioning keys. :(

Can anybody help out here?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If your keyboard doesn't work while loading the BIOS (that loads before Ubuntu and is OS independent), it's not an Ubuntu problem, not related to any update. I can't think of any way in which a OS can change how the BIOS manages keyboard. Installing another OS (Ubuntu 11.04 or Windows) is not going to solve this.

The most likely cause is some hardware related problem. You can try to attach an USB keyboard to the computer and enter the BIOS from it.

If you don't fear screwdrivers and the laptop is not under warranty you should check the connection of the keyboard to the main-board. Otherwise is time to get it to a computer repair shop.

Answer (score 0):

It's a hardware problem, but likely a very simple one.  Check your `Fn` key isn't stuck down, which on an *Acer Aspire* laptop would change the behavior of the letters `UIOPJKLM`, `F1`-`F12`, and the arrow keys.  Other compact laptops (those with no separate numberpad) can have similar issues.